# Call tokenize with xsl stylesheet 2.0 does not work

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm a beginner in XSL. I've xsl stylesheet 2.0 with xml version = 1.0 but when I call standard function 'tokenize'(In xsl:for-each select="lijst/sectie) , it doesn't work. Why ?

I've a problem with the following instructions :

I've looked for the function Tokenize and I thought it was all right. With xsl stylesheet 2.0 and a xml version 1.0, I saw a few example on the web.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:import href="..\\rg.xsl" />

<xsl:variable name="sortby" select="lijst/sort" /> 
<html>

<body>
 <!-- Rest of the code -->
  <table border="1"> 

   <xsl:for-each select="lijst/sectie"> 
     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$sortby='0'"> 
          <xsl:apply-templates select="element">
             <xsl:sort select="substring-before(.,'|')" order="ascending"/> 
             <xsl:with-param name="sortedby" select="$sortby"/>           
          </xsl:apply-templates>    
        </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="element">
          <!-- Problem with the line in below -->
          <xsl:variable name="ElementValues" select="tokenize(.,'|')"/>
          <xsl:sort select="substring-before(.,'|')" order="ascending"/> 
          <xsl:with-param name="sortedby" select="$sortby"/>    
        </xsl:apply-templates>
     </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>

   </xsl:for-each>


   </table>

   </body>
   </html>

   </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: *"it doesn't work*" is not a good description of a problem. How are you applying the transformation and how does it fail? -- Note that you need an XSLT 2.0 processor to execute XSLT 2.0-only features.

Comment: What is it exactly you want to achieve, which error do you get? You are trying to declare variable which you don't seem to use at all, and I think you do it inside of  `apply-templates`, one of the few places where that is not possible if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

My guess (because it's a mistake that many people make) is that you are using an XSLT 1.0 processor. Specifying version="2.0" in your stylesheet doesn't make your XSLT processor magically understand XSLT 2.0 if the software was last updated in 2001.